# vue2 composition api why does watch not fire

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I hope this is simple.
I have this component called "brands", it's code looks like this:

```
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
  ref,
  toRefs,
  watch,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import { useTrackProductImpressions } from "@logic/track-product-impressions";
import BrandComponent from "@components/brand/brand.component.vue";
import { Brand } from "@/_core/models";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Brands",
  components: { BrandComponent },
  emits: ["onMore"],
  props: {
    brands: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
    hasMoreResults: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    itemsToShow: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const { itemsToShow, brands } = toRefs(props);
    const count = ref(0);
    const skip = computed(() => {
      if (!itemsToShow.value) return 0;
      return count.value * itemsToShow.value;
    });

    const more = () => {
      count.value++;
      instance.proxy.$emit("onMore");
    };

    console.log(brands);

    watch(brands, (impressions: Brand[]) => {
      console.log(impressions);
      if (!impressions.length) return;
      const route = instance.proxy.$route;
      useTrackProductImpressions(impressions, route);
    });

    return {
      skip,
      more,
    };
  },
});
```

As you can see, I have set up a **watch** on the **brands** property, so that when it's defined it will track it. The problem is, it never gets called.
The first console log, I can see the brands ref and can see it's value is an array, but in the watch method, it never gets invoked.

The component is never initialised without brands:

```
<brands
  :brands="brands"
  :hasMoreResults="brandsHasMoreResults"
  :itemsToShow="brandsItemsToShow"
  :total="brandsTotal"
  @onMore="brandsFetchMore()"
  v-if="brands.length"
/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your parent component modifying the `brands` prop? Are you replacing the whole array or mutating it? How? Do you know the [reactivity caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) of Vue 2?

Comment: I didn't know about the caveats; I am actually replacing the entire array

Comment: If you want to have your watch fired initially, just to mention it you can do it with 
```{ immediate: true }``` as it's 3rd Param.